# Pre-dispatch Error

Tags: substrate-node-template, transactions, weight, error, signed-extensions

I took a look at the check-weight SignedExtention to see what happens when a block is full. It appears that it returns an error `InvalidTransaction::ExhaustsResources`. It think it puts it back into the transaction pool but cannot find any documentation around this.

What happens when an error occurs in pre-dispatch?

How can I put something back into the transaction pool and reprioritize if in pre-dispatch? Perhaps, using something like [ValidTransaction](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.ValidTransaction.html).

Comment: Does anything in specific happen when you try to use `ValidTransaction`?

Comment: @JustinFrevert The trait [SignedExtesion](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.SignedExtension.html#tymethod.pre_dispatch) pre-dispatch returns, [Pre](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.SignedExtension.html#associatedtype.Pre), which is a type that is passed to post-dispatch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transaction is not really put back if verification fails with `InvalidTransaction::ExhaustsResources`, it is just kept in the transaction pool.

You can find some notes about it here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/client/transaction-pool#invalid-transaction

And also look at the code where it happens here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/basic-authorship/src/basic_authorship.rs#L466-L496

The invalid txs that are not `InvalidTransaction::ExhaustsResources` are pushed to `unqueue_invalid`: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/basic-authorship/src/basic_authorship.rs#L495

to be removed afterwards from the transaction pool: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/basic-authorship/src/basic_authorship.rs#L507

About how to give them a higher priority after being invalid... I am afraid that it might not be possible without modifying the client since `validate()` can only return either `ValidTransaction` or `TransactionValidityError`. Might be a workaround I am not able to think about right now. You could solve your issue resending the tx with a higher `priority` though. If 2 transactions are received from the same sender with an identical `nonce`, only one transaction can be included on-chain. The client will choose the transaction with a higher `priority` to be stored in the transaction pool.